# File written by json.dump() not readable by json.load()

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm creating a setup script for my Python project. The script reads build configurations from a json file like so:

```
with open('setup.conf','r') as configfile:
    config = json.load(configfile)
```

which works perfectly. Later in the script, I constrain myself to a part of that object and write this part to another file:

```
config = config[arg]
[...]
with open('kivy/app.conf','w') as appconfig:
    json.dump(config,appconfig)
```

which at least does not generate any errors.
Upon startup of my main app, I then want to read the file I just created:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
with open(path + '/app.conf','r') as configfile:
    config = json.load(configfile)
```

This, however, fails with a

```
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

indicating that the json written by json.dump() itself is invalid from the very first character onwards. The data itself is as unsuspicious as it can get, all plain ASCII characters, no weird line endings etc.:

```
{"deploy_server": false, "run_server": true, "server": "127.0.0.1", "run_app": true, "deploy_iOS": false, "user": "", "debug": true, "path": "", "deploy_android": false, "port": "8000"}
```

I don't have the slightest idea where this could be coming from. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I discovered that the very same code above works in a live interpreter session. I conclude from this that there must be something strange going on in the code surrounding this, but I'm at loss here as well: There probably is an obvious elephant in the room, but I can't see it. The surrounding code looks like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from foodcalendar import CalendarWidget
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
import os
import requests
import json


[...]

class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp,self).__init__()
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        print path
        with open(path + '/app.conf','r') as configfile:
            for r in configfile:
                print r
                config = json.loads(r)
        self.server = config["server"]
```

**UPDATE 2**

It turns out that the error I'm facing is somehow related to the `requests` module: If I comment out `import requests`, everything works as expected, but I'm clueless as to why this happens, since the docs of the `json` and `requests` modules remain silent about any incompatibilities...

**UPDATE 3**

This seems to be a machine dependent issue. I ran my code on another machine, and there it ran flawlessly. Python is version 2.7.12, OS is Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64, kernel version is 4.4.0.38-generic on both machines...

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the same file you wrote to?

Comment: @Blender: Yes, the file I'm referencing is the correct one.

Comment: Try to write in mode "wb".

Comment: @JulienD: I already tried that to no avail...

Comment: After writing the file with `json.dump()`, what are the file contents?

Comment: Just a wild guess... You probably have some garbage at the beginning of the file. Maybe BOM? What does `print(repr(open(filaname).read()))` say?

Comment: @zvone: This gives me the string back as is, no weird things happening... Also, `file app.conf` in the terminal results in `app.conf: ASCII text, with no line terminators`, so nothing weird here, either...

Comment: @JohnGordon: The file content is exactly the string in my original post.

Comment: The string in the question looks like it has leading whitespace. Can you confirm, perhaps with a hex dump of the first few bytes?

Comment: @tripleee: The file has no leading whitespace, this is just the code block formatting of stackexchange what you're seeing...

Comment: Your code formatting was slightly off. I tried to fix that, but I had to change the indentation after the `class` (or rather, not touch it while changing the enclosing indentation); could you please review?

Comment: How are you `import` ing `json` and `requests`? I don't see the code for that in the question.

Comment: @tripleee: this is the full list of my imports: `from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from foodcalendar import CalendarWidget
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
import os
#import requests
import json
`

Comment: This error *simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)*, suggests that the file is empty. Added to the fact that in works in an interactive session it makes me say: the file you try to read is not the one you expect. You should control twice all the paths, at least one is likely to be wrong

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Already done so: The setup script `setup.py` is in the projects root directory, it creates `kivy/app.conf`, which is the file in question, confirmed by `rm kivy/app.conf` followed by `kivy/./main.py` resulting in "no such file or directory", and afterwards `./setup.py` followed by `kivy/./main.py` reproduces the error. Additionally, everything works as long as I don't use the `requests` module...

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include this information, and ideally reduce it to just a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I copied and pasted the text you supplied as being the file contents, into a variable.

```
>>> import json
>>> a=""" {"deploy_server": false, "run_server": true, "server": "127.0.0.1", "run_app": true, "deploy_iOS": false, "user": "", "debug": true, "path": "", "deploy_android": false, "port": "8000"}"""
>>> json.loads(a)
{'deploy_android': False, 'run_app': True, 'port': '8000', 'debug': True, 'deploy_server': False, 'server': '127.0.0.1', 'user': '', 'run_server': True, 'deploy_iOS': False, 'path': ''}
>>>
```

All works.  You could try this also.  If you get the same result as I did with this as literal text, then you can be sure the error is with the reading and writing the file.  You could try a 'print' of what you are about to feed to json.loads

Comment: The string literal copied and pasted works for me, too. And it gets even weirder:Following your idea, I tried json.loads() with a file row rather than json.load() on the file, i.e.: `with open(path + '/app.conf','r') as configfile:
            for r in configfile:
                print r
                config = json.loads(r)` which gives me the same exception. Weirdly though, the very same code works in an interpreter session, so there must be something weird going on in the surrounding code that I'm missing all the time..